# wxpython ctrl+x shortcut does not work

Tags: wxpython

I'm running this wxpython app in windows 7.  For some reason when I press `ctrl+x` on my keyboard, the frame does not close.

However if I change the binding from `text='quit\tCtrl+x'` to `text='quit\tCtrl+q'` or any other character than `x`, the frame closes.

Does `ctrl+x` have any special significance in wxpython that is preventing the frame from being closed?

```
import os
import wx
class MainMe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, size=(300, 300), title = 'test frame')
        wx.TextCtrl(parent=self, style =wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_NO_VSCROLL)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        exitId, aboutId = wx.NewId(), wx.NewId()
        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(id=aboutId, text='about\tCtrl+a', help='more information')
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(id=exitId, text='quit\tCtrl+x', help="close")

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu, title='File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAbout, source=menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, source=menuExit)

        self.Show()

    def onAbout(self, e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog( self, "A small text editor", "About Sample Editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def onExit(self, e):
        self.Close(True)

a = wx.App()
f = MainMe()
a.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+x while the text ctrl has focus is the shortcut for cutting text, along with Ctrl+c for copy & Ctrl+v for paste.

Comment: Is there any way to override these defaults?

Comment: Id be inclined not to as users expect ctrl+x to be cut, they will go to cut something and they get exited instead.

Comment: I understand, but for other hotkeys, are there ways to override them?